# RecyclerView.Adapter hook method issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

As the title suggests I have an issue with a RecyclerView Adapter callback hooks.  I currently have 6 items in a `RecyclerView`, these views are custom views that have their own logic, animations etc.. These views are fine, and work as expected.  However I have an issue when I show a `FrameLayout` over the `RecyclerView` layout.  The `FrameLayout` is nothing special, and I change its Visiblity from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`.

When this happens the RecyclerView calls these methods:

```
@Override public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)

@Override public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)

@Override public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)
```

These are called for ALL positions (0 - 5).  At this point I stop any animations in my custom views, and reset them to a ready state. So far this seems reasonable, the views are obscured, so these hooks are called.

**The Issue**

When I set the overlay `FrameLayout` from `VISIBLE` to `GONE` again the `RecyclerView` calls `onBindViewHolder` for the first 4 positions (0-3), it is not called for positions 4 & 5 (confirmed with break points and logging).  This means the views in these positions don't initialise themselves - obviously this is done in `onBindViewHolder`.

So I'm asking why `onBindViewHolder` isn't called for the positions it previously recycled, when ALL 6 views in the RecyclerView are visible on screen at the same time?

I would post code, but in this instance I'm only talking about the logic and hooks of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class, my implementation is merely using these hooks.

**EDIT**

I have a working solution, rather than setting up the custom view in `onBindViewHolder` I use :

To reset the view:

```
@Override public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)
```

To initialise the view:

```
@Override public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)
```

These 2 hook methods seem logical opposites of each other, and work as such, however it still is a mystery why `onBindViewHolder` isn't called for all views.